# Assigning points based off string

Tags: python

I'm trying to create some type of scoring system using regex and strings. If I had a scoringlist:

```
string = "foo is my favorite bar ever!"
score = 0
scorelist = {
'\bfoo\b': score += 10,
'hello (foo (bar)?|there)': score -= 15
}
```

Now, I know this is completely incorrect (and even unfinished considering string wasn't assessed) for trying to generate a new score but don't have any guidance on what to do. Hopefully this is somewhat self-explanatory with the bad code on how I can get this to work.

EDIT: The scorelist is supposed to hold the matches and the outcome if the match is true.  So, in this case, if the word foo is (well, supposed to be) found in the string, score would +10.

Comment: Your code is not self-explanatory. Please describe what rules you're trying to implement and give an example of how a string should be scored.

Comment: if the only tool you know is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail - regex is a powerful hammer, but not the right tool for this job. Your problem domain is NLP, one of the most complex subjects in CS, and you better spent a few hours on it instead of trying to reinvent the wheel (look for classifiers).

Answer (score 0):

I like this approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

scorelist = [
    ('\bfoo\b', 10),
    (re.compile('hello (foo (bar)?|there)'), -15),
    ]

score = 0
mystring = "foo is my favorite bar ever!"
for pattern, pscore in scorelist:
    if isinstance(pattern, basestring):
        if pattern in mystring:
            score += pscore
    else:
        if pattern.search(mystring):
            score += pscore
```

So for each `(pattern, pscore)` tuple in `scorelist`, if the pattern is a string, look for that string in `mystring`. If it's there, increment `score` by `pscore`.

If `pattern` isn't not a string, then treat it as a regular expression and evaluate it against `mystring`. If it matches, increment `score` by `pscore`.

It's a tiny amount of work up front that makes the system easy to extend in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators work well here:

```
class Matcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.patterns = []

    def case(self, pattern):
        def decorator(f):
            self.patterns += [(re.compile(pattern), f)]
            return f
        return decorator

    def match(self, s):
        for pattern, action in self.patterns:
            if pattern.search(s):
                action(self)

m = Matcher()

@m.case(r'\bfoo\b')
def fooMatched(self):
    self.score += 10

@m.case(r'hello (foo (bar)?|there)')
def helloMatched(self):
    self.score -= 15

m.match("foo is my favorite bar ever!")

print m.score
```